# video file loaded sucussefully when run my website locally but not after publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, web

I have a overlay video playing in the background and it works fine when I run the website locally 
after deploying to azure I got this error message in browser console

HTTP load failed with status 404. Load of media resource https://biblo4.azurewebsites.net/Content/theme/video/Computer.mp4 failed.

Comment: Is that the actual link? Because it returns _"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."_

Comment: Yes this is the actual link. And this is my problem. I am using visual studio 2015 and TFS automatically deploy to azure web service. So I've included the file into my project then pushed the changes to TFS. All changes are reflected to the deployed website except this file not founded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer for my question
I had to edit web.config file to allow server send video files

```
<staticContent> 
    <mimeMap fileExtension="mp4" mimeType="video/mp4"/> 
    <mimeMap fileExtension="m4v" mimeType="video/m4v"/> 
    <mimeMap fileExtension="ogg" mimeType="video/ogg"/> 
    <mimeMap fileExtension="ogv" mimeType="video/ogg"/> 
    <mimeMap fileExtension="webm" mimeType="video/webm"/> 
</staticContent>
```

Comment: Although my code is working on the server now, but I still wonder, why it was working locally but not when deployed.